# Windows boot option not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

i'm a new user at Ubuntu, and i think i've lost my boot to Windows. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and i'm not an expert of this issues (but i can move through the console).
Please, would you mind to help me? I only want to have Windows at my bootmenu working (now it is but it doen't work).

My pastefile is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bNVKKZXPc5/

Thanks a lot, i'm desperated and about to remove Linux and have only Windows, please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

As i see in sda1 there is Windows, so do not worry.
Try to install grub-customizer from this code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt update

sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Then you have to search(Win command) grub customizer and make sure that grub works, and there is Windows Boot Manager